# How do you get the max value for a foreign key value in models.py file?

Tags: python, html, django

This is my html file

```
{% for member in member_list %}
    {% for batting in batting_list %}
        {% if member.id == batting.member.id %}
            {{ batting }}
            <br>
            {{ batting.match.id }}
            <br>
            {{ batting.runs }}
            <br>
            <hr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is my models.py file

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Batting(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    runs = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return str('{0} {1} scored {2} runs'.format(self.member, self.match.date, self.runs))
```

I am trying to figure out how I show the max runs for a member x in the html file.  Currently I have been able to do it for the whole Batting table but not for the individual member! Any help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query with:

```
from django.db.models import Max

member.batting_set.aggregate(
    max_runs=Max('batting__runs')
)['max_runs']
```

This will be `None` if no related `Batting`s exist.

You can annotate the `Member`s queryset with:

```
from django.db.models import Max

member_list = Member.objects.annotate(
    max_runs=Max('batting__runs')
)
```

and thus then render this with:

```
{% for member in member_list %}
    {{ member.max_runs }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Does this go into the views.py file or under the member class in the models.py?

Comment: So in my views i had to make this `member_list=Member.objects.order_by('teamsPlayedFor').annotate(max_runs=Max('batting__runs')).annotate(min_runs=Min('batting__runs'))`

Comment: @Joelad: you can do it in one annotate, so `.annotat(max_runs=..., min_runs=...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `annotate` over members to get their batting with highest runs value.

```
from django.db.models import Max
Member.objects.annotate(max_runs=Max("batting_set__runs"))
```

Then show `{{ member.max_runs }}` on your template.

Comment: Notice the `batting_set` instead of only `batting` - the default `related_name` for a foreign key is `<field name>_set`. You ca change that by adding `related_name="batting"` to your `member` foreign key at `Batting`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create annotation in your queryset which will contain highest runs for a member.

```
from django.db.models import Max

Member.objects.annotate(max_runs=Max('batting__runs'))
```

You can access it like a regular field

```
member_object.max_runs
```

I'm not sure about your view, but for a ListView the class will look like this

```
class MemberView(ListView):
    template_name = 'tmp.html'
    model = Member

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Member.objects.annotate(max_runs=Max('batting__runs')).all()
```